# Selection sort on a list in c

Tags: c, list, sorting

```
typedef struct node {
struct node *prev;
int index;
int val;
struct node *next;
} nod;
nod *p, *q, *r, *prim;

void print()     
{  p=prim; 
     while(p!=NULL) 
       {
           printf("%d ",p->val); 
           p=p->next; 
       }
}

void swap(nod *p, nod *max) {
    int tmp=p->val;
    p->val=max->val;
    max->val=tmp;
}

void sort() {
    q=prim->next;
    nod *max;
    while(p!=NULL) {
        max=prim;
        while(q->index<p->index) {
            if(q->val>max->val) {
                max=q;
            }
            q=q->next;
        }
        swap(p,max);
        p=p->prev;
    }
  }

//some other functions that work fine

int main()
{
    int n=10, index=0;
    //prim=(nod *) malloc(sizeof(nod)); done in add
    prim=NULL;
    do {
        add(rand()%100, &index); //added succesufully
    } while(index<10);
   printf("Before sorting:\n");
   print();
   sortare();
   printf("\nAfter sorting:\n");
   print();
}
```

I aplied something like selection sort on this list, but i think it's bugged because it's [not really sorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCo9J.png). 
No errors. The problem is in algorithm.

Comment: Please don't add filler text. Fill it with actual details instead! Like your input, the expected and actual output, and what you have done to try and debug your program.

Comment: where are you invoking `sort()`? In `main()` you call `sortare()`. Does that call `sort()`?

Comment: i think i'll try to extract the values from list in an array, sort it with easy algorithm and put them back sorted

Comment: in my code its called sortare, but the problem is not in this

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node *prev;
    int index;
    int val;
    struct node *next;
} nod;
nod *p, *q, *last, *prim;

void swap(nod *p, nod *max) {
    int tmp=p->val;
    p->val=max->val;
    max->val=tmp;
}

void sort() {
nod *max;
p=last;
while(p!=NULL && p->index>0) {
    max=prim;
    q=prim->next;
    while(q!=NULL && q->index<=p->index) {
        if(q->val>max->val) {
            max=q;
        }
        q=q->next;
    }
    swap(p,max);
    p=p->prev;
}
}
```

Selection sort on a double-linked list